# docker-compose_thehive_1 exited with code 1

Tags: docker-compose, ubuntu-22.04

I need help.
i use docker compose file
thehive version 5.2
elasticsearch version 7.17.13
casandra version 4
cortex version 3.1
all images is running normally unless Thehive started with error
"docker-compose_thehive_1 exited with code 1"

thank you.

docker-compose_thehive_1 exited with code 1
thehive_1        | Using elasticsearch address = elasticsearch with index thehive
thehive_1        | Using S3 http://minio:9002 bucket=thehive
thehive_1        | Starting thehive with config file /tmp/thehive-knxisU.conf
thehive_1        | 22:25:51.447 [main] WARN kamon.Init -- Kamon is DISABLED. No instrumentation, reporters, or context propagation will be applied on this process. Restart the process with kamon.enabled=yes to restore Kamon's functionality
thehive_1        | [info] o.t.t.TheHiveStarter [] Starting TheHive v5.2.6-1
thehive_1        | [info] o.t.t.TheHiveStarter [] Running on Java Amazon.com Inc. 11.